# How to use ion-tabs along with menu and page animation?

Tags: angular, animation, ionic-framework

[image]

I am new to ionic. I am trying to implement side menu for which I have used ion-menu in the header and ion-tabs at the bottom. I have used "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions" for page transitions while switching between tabs. But I don't want my header to be a part of this animation. 
However, I also tried to keep header separate, but then it overlaps the tab's pages.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the nativepagetransitions plugin and confine transitions to the web layer, your header problem disappears.

Right-to-left transitions for navigating between root pages is an anti-pattern and is best avoided. Refer to the standard OS apps for how they implement this (e.g. App Store on iOS and Play Store on Android).

**Update**

I actually tried my previous suggestion, documented [here](https://github.com/alex-steinberg/animate-tabs-ionic4), and it didn't work. I will continue working on this as I would also like to see a solution to the problem. If I find a solution, I will push it to the [repo](https://github.com/alex-steinberg/animate-tabs-ionic4) and update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your effort. But I am not sure how exactly are you suggesting to implement fadeOutContent() or fadeInContent(). Can you help me with that ?